# Is Asciidoc markup programmatically extendable (by existen implementation, like RST)?

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

**reStructuredText** allow you extend/rewrite writer for its markup. So you can add new type of embedded objects or introduce new sub-language by defined API.

Is this possible with Asciidoc (*original* Python implementation or Ruby *asciidoctor*)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes to both, though the ways to extend each are different. In the Python implementation there's a conf file you use to create additional regex matchers. In asciidoctor (ruby) there is a full extension system built into versions starting at 0.1.4 (though it was at preview level in 0.1.4). Visit http://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#extension-points for more information about extensions in asciidoctor. http://asciidoc.org/userguide.html#X7 for asciidoc.